# Instructions for bag 2 with id 135149

Tags: set-identification

My kids thinks it’s something form a Star Wars bag but we don’t have instructions anymore.  Appreciate your help. [image]

Answer (score 2):

Based on the red & blue 1x2 brackets, the 2x2 dark blue curved slopes and the minifig binoculars, this can be identified as [set 75317 "The Mandalorian and Child"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75317-1)

[image: set image]